# Vue Component is not highlighting code syntex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, progressive-web-apps, prismjs

I have a very simple VueJS application and I have a TinyMCE editor in my one of the component which uses Prism for highlighting code syntex. While typing in TinyMCE editor, the code looks fine as normally prism highlights the syntex when you're writing in tinymce editor. I save all the html code and render it on a different component.

The Vue component renders the code incorrectly. [image: Incorrectly rendered image]

[image: This is how it looks in TinyMCE plugin]

I have searched everywhere but I didn't find any suitable thing to correct this. I will show you the component code.

```
<template>
  <v-row>
    <v-col cols="6">
      <v-card class="blog-data">
        <div v-html="blogs"></div>
      </v-card>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</template>
```

What I am doing is, I am requesting the data from an api and saving into `blogs` variable and then pass this as a raw html inside the vue component.

Please let me know, what wrong I have done here so that I can fix this correctly. By the way, I am trying to embed html editor for blogging purpose which can highlight code having lot of formatting features. My Site is available on https://www.springcoders.co.in

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue, all we needed to do is to manually assign the data to the component and then in vue mounted hook we needed to use Prism APi `Prism.highlightAll()` works very well.